# In reactjs modal close button is not working

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am use bootstrap modal in reactjs project. Here is the link of package which i have installed in my project: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive-modal

When, I click on open the modal button then it is working, but when i click on close button then close button is not working. I am using the hooks in my project. Below, I have mentioned my code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Modal from 'react-responsive-modal'

const Login = () => {
    const [open, openModal] = useState(false)

    const onOpenModal = () => {
        openModal({open: true})
    };
    const onCloseModal = () => {
        openModal({open: false})
    };

    return(
        <div>
            <h1>Login Form</h1>
            <button onClick={onOpenModal}>Open modal</button>
            <Modal open={open} onClose={onCloseModal} center>
            <h2>Simple centered modal</h2>
            </Modal>            
        </div>
    )
}

export default Login;
```

Comment: Hi Sahil, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is working fine :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because, you are setting object in state,

```
openModal({open: true})
```

This will store object in state.

`setState` require's direct value which needs to be change, your `setState` must be this,

```
const onOpenModal = () => {
    openModal(!open)  //This will negate the previous state
};

const onCloseModal = () => {
    openModal(!open) //This will negate the previous state
};
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dyooef)

---

You can simplify your code and just use 1 change handle for your modal,

```
const Login = () => {
    const [open, openModal] = useState(false)

    const toggleModal = () => {
        openModal(!open)
    };
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>Login Form</h1>
            <button onClick={toggleModal}>Open modal</button>
            <Modal open={open} onClose={toggleModal} center>
            <h2>Simple centered modal</h2>
            </Modal>            
        </div>
    )
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-sjxxpz)

Comment: I want to open the modal on button click from my navigation bar link. How, I can pass this to my other component as props?

Comment: yes you can pass function to other component and call when required.

Answer (score 2):

Your naming of the model hook is misleading and you're using the setState part of the Hook wrong, probably mixing it up with the this.setState convention for non-Hook React code.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Modal from 'react-responsive-modal'

const Login = () => {
    const [modalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false)

    const onOpenModal = () => {
        setModalOpen(true)
    };
    const onCloseModal = () => {
        setModalOpen(false)
    };

    return(
        <div>
            <h1>Login Form</h1>
            <button onClick={onOpenModal}>Open modal</button>
            <Modal open={modalOpen} onClose={onCloseModal} center>
            <h2>Simple centered modal</h2>
            </Modal>            
        </div>
    )
}

export default Login;
```

Comment: I don't agree with *Your naming of the model hook is misleading*.